# How to import UMD file from a react component with NWB lib into a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i'm getting in trouble trying to show my react component inside a html page, i'm exporting to UMD with nwb lib. I want to use my react component into a non react page, like a simple html page, and be able to pass data to it. But browser does not recognize my component name "RosaChat".

My index.html file

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>react-webpack-wrapper-example</title>
    <script src="umd/react-beautiful-chat.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    Hello World!
    <script>
      ReactDOM.render(RosaChat, document.getElementById("content"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My nwb configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  type: "react-component",
  npm: {
    cjs: true,
    esModules: true,
    umd: {
      global: "RosaChat",
      externals: {
        react: "React"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Main component Launcher:

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChatWindow from "./ChatWindow";
import launcherIcon from "./../assets/logo-no-bg.svg";
import launcherIconActive from "./../assets/close-icon.png";

class Launcher extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      launcherIcon,
      isOpen: false,
      count: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
    if (this.props.handleClick !== undefined) {
      this.props.handleClick();
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
      });
    }
  }

  updateCount = () => {
    if (this.state.isOpen) {
      this.setState({ count: 0 });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const isOpen = this.props.hasOwnProperty("isOpen")
      ? this.props.isOpen
      : this.state.isOpen;
    const classList = ["sc-launcher", isOpen ? "opened" : ""];
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className={classList.join(" ")}
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        >
          <MessageCount count={this.state.count} isOpen={isOpen} />
          <img className={"sc-open-icon"} src={launcherIconActive} />
          <img className={"sc-closed-icon"} src={launcherIcon} />
        </div>
        <ChatWindow
          messageList={this.props.messageList}
          onUserInputSubmit={this.props.onMessageWasSent}
          agentProfile={this.props.agentProfile}
          isOpen={isOpen}
          messageCount={this.updateCount}
          onClose={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          showEmoji={this.props.showEmoji}
          showFile={this.props.showFile}
          onKeyPress={this.props.onKeyPress}
          onKeyPressDebounce={this.props.onKeyPressDebounce}
          onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MessageCount = props => {
  if (props.count === 0 || props.isOpen === true) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div className={"sc-new-messsages-count"}>{props.count}</div>;
};

Launcher.propTypes = {
  onMessageWasReceived: PropTypes.func,
  onMessageWasSent: PropTypes.func,
  newMessagesCount: PropTypes.number,
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  handleClick: PropTypes.func,
  messageList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  showEmoji: PropTypes.bool,
  showFile: PropTypes.bool,
  onKeyPress: PropTypes.func,
  onDelete: PropTypes.func
};

Launcher.defaultProps = {
  newMessagesCount: 0
};

export default Launcher;
```

UMD FILE snippet:

```js
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
 if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
  module.exports = factory(require("react"));
 else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
  define(["react"], factory);
 else if(typeof exports === 'object')
  exports["RosaChat"] = factory(require("react"));
 else
  root["RosaChat"] = factory(root["React"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the question. What is the error you are getting? If you detail what steps you have taken to solve the problem you are more likely to get a response.